Calles in KCachegrind
Question for KCachegrind experts. I couldn't find a description for the "Self" field in the "All Callees" table. Can you please tell me what data is displayed there?
The site has a comprehensive description of the KCachegrind interface. For example:
How to interpret results from kcachegrind
KCachegrind interpretation confusion
But it was not possible to find an answer to a specific question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
